LLM generation problem - only returning gibberish?
I am trying to load a model from path into llamaindex with the HuggingfaceLLM class like this:
from llama_index.llms.huggingface import HuggingFaceLLM

llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
   context_window=2048,
   max_new_tokens=300,
   generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0.5, "do_sample": True},
   #query_wrapper_prompt=query_wrapper_prompt,
   tokenizer_name="local_path/leo-hessianai-7B-AWQ",
   model_name="local_path/leo-hessianai-7B-AWQ",
   device_map="auto"
)

The folders are downloaded from the huggingface-hub and the model is loading, however, when I query it, it returns only gibberish (like hohohohohohohohohohohohohoho and so on)
The source nodes are plausible and correct, I checked that, it is only the generating part that appears to be wrong.
Is there anything I am missing here? When I load the model from the hub with the link it's fine, but that does not work in the IDE (and Ollama etc. are also not an option).
I appreciate any help, thanks!

Can you share your prompt, prompt template and link to the model? Returning gibberish could be because the model requires a specific prompt template. Sometimes the libraries are handling the template but I know llamaindex not well enough to be sure.

This model is not a regular model, it has a custom quantization scheme that is probably not supported out of the box by the library you're using. See
https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/leo-hessianai-7B-AWQ#about-awq
Indeed, in the vllm example, they specify the quantization
https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/leo-hessianai-7B-AWQ#serving-this-model-from-vllm
Not sure what llama index is, but I would try a different model if I was you
